# React Blob to File upload via Node endpoint - file is corrupt

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer, react-image-crop

I've built a Slack-style avatar image upload and crop feature, and I can't get the cropped image to save without corruption. The original file upload, using the same endpoint and method, works just fine. It's the cropped copy, created manually from a Blob, that is always corrupt.

Steps are pretty simple:

1. Select and upload an image file
2. Crop (react-image-crop) appears
3. Select area, hit Save

In Step 1, the file is uploaded when the file input changes. File is sent to a streaming endpoint which uploads the file to an s3 bucket.

```
<button type="button">Upload</button>
<input 
    type="file" 
    accept="image/*"
    onChange={onFileChange} 
/>

...

const onFileChange = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let uploadedFile = e.target.files[0];
    await onSave(uploadedFile);
};
```

The uploadedFile var is the File object returned from the input control. This works great! No issues, yet.

[image]

In Step 3, once you've selected an area of the image, a Blob is produced by react-image-crop.

```
const getCroppedImage = (source, config) => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const scaleX = source.naturalWidth / source.width;
    const scaleY = source.naturalHeight / source.height;
    canvas.width = config.width;
    canvas.height = config.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.drawImage(
        source,
        config.x * scaleX,
        config.y * scaleY,
        config.width * scaleX,
        config.height * scaleY,
        0,
        0,
        config.width,
        config.height
    );

    let mimeType = mime.lookup(userProfile.image_file.split(".").at(-1));

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        canvas.toBlob(blob => {
            if (!blob) {
                reject(new Error("Canvas is empty"));
                return;
            }
            resolve(blob); //***THIS BLOB...
        }, mimeType);
    });
};
```

This Blob is valid, because I display the selected area on the screen before saving:

```
const AvatarPreview = () => {
    if (activeAvatar) {
        return <ImageCropper imageToCrop={activeAvatar} onImageCropped={onImageCropped} />;
    }
    return <Icon icon="bi:person" />;
};
```

I stuff the Blob produced by react-image-crop, into a File object because that's what my code expects, just like Step 1.

```
const onImageCropped = croppedBlob => { //***IS PASSED IN HERE
    let croppedImg = URL.createObjectURL(croppedBlob);
    setActiveAvatar(croppedImg);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(croppedBlob);
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        let { result } = reader;
        let resultMimeType = result.split(";")[0].split(":")[1];
        let croppedFile = new File([result], userProfile.image_file, { type: resultMimeType }); //***NEW File object, from Blob
        setCroppedAvatar(croppedFile);
    }, false);
};

<button type="button" onClick={() => onSave(croppedAvatar)}>Save</button>
```

The "result" in the FileReader load above is the base64 image data:

```
'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAQwAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAlkZXNjAAAA8AAAAHRyWFlaAAABZAAAABRnWFlaAAABeAAAABRiWFlaAAABjAAAABRyVFJDAAABoAAAAChnVFJDAAABoAAAAChiVFJDAAABoAAAACh3dHB0AAAByAAAABRjcHJ0AAAB3AAAADxtbHVjAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAMZW5VUwAAAFgAAAAcAHMAUgBHAEIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA…QCMFWeFZ9u3fPsWY3hh9uVHWllbSwtGASrIOQc1t6rt0OBqG6x7aVfdY859pnIwfDDhCfpwBUyaSus4VZO+susGGM60zrB1TuEjx5Ov76FBKUgNTltIQlP4UpQghKQMAAAADHApt6lv1x1HeHrzdny9KkJbDrpHLhQhKNx91EJBJ9SSaQkLS+4HTwvalKvmQMZ/PFa8hBCRntnirYUDqVYtEWlQ8JYJSrv8vnTy6W2h5/qBYmCgqbcmtgLSMg+YUyYD4aUUqTlJ4I+td+FLethRhai0sgoUOCg+hFPBwcxjruUie1k/VDOmenKkIcS2iJCzyeAAmvF7qjqFzVWurzfHV7jJluKBJ/hBwP6VL1u+KvqlD0lL0VeLt+2rZLjmO25MyqSwNuPK7nKh8l7vlioFejqU8tx453EnIPcmrWrvW5VFf6zK0GifTWs1n6TRoUrIaDZBSeDSVUzyMTY7gBIORR/EcXwTnFEozfc0xVwOYT/2Q=='
```

The new File object seems legit to me:

[image]

I then send the image through the endpoint again, and it's uploaded. It appears in the bucket, and the file size seems legit (not 0KB like a broken stream would indicate.)

However, upon downloading and attempting to open the file, it's corrupt. I guess I'm missing an option somewhere...some little tweak that would make this work? Is the File object not formed correctly? How do I troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is in. It was, of course, one line of code to make it all work. All I had to do was change the way the FileReader loaded the result:

```
const onImageCropped = async croppedBlob => {
    let croppedImg = URL.createObjectURL(croppedBlob);
    let mimeType = croppedBlob.type;
    setActiveAvatar(croppedImg);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(croppedBlob); //Fixed the issue
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        let { result } = reader;
        let croppedFile = new File([result], userProfile.image_file, { type: mimeType });
        setCroppedAvatar(croppedFile);
    }, false);
};
```

It turned out to be more elegant, anyhow. Using FileReader's readAsArrayBuffer instead worked. I'm guessing there was extra info in the buffer when using readAsDataUrl, corrupting the image.